# Python, Selenium, presence_of_element_located always returns an object (is never false)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I use presence_of_element_located, the function never fails to return (i.e. always returns an element). What it is that it's returning I don't know. This means that if can't be used in the way it's supposed to, in conjunction with ....Wait...Until(....).

For example, the following runs without an error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")

WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
    # Cookie
    lambda x: EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@title="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"]'))
)

print("Done!")
```

despite the fact that, as is readily verified, there is no element with title "ZZZZZZZ...." on youtube.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Call is wrong, remove the lambda and use:

```
x = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@title="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"]'))
)
```

The `until()` method is expected another method to be passed. Then it will call that method to determine the expected return:

```
def until(self, method, message=''):
    """Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the 
    return value is not False."""
```

Passing a lambda the way you did will always return the object `presence_of_element_located`, therefore it cannot be false.

Answer (score 0):

you should not wrap the provided expected conditions (the EC methods) in a lambda. the expected conditions already return a closure (lambda). you need the lambda only when writing your own conditions

wrong (extraneous lambda):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
    # Cookie
    lambda x: EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@title="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"]'))
    ^^^^^^^^^
)
```

correct:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
    # Cookie
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@title="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"]'))
)
```

---

it seems you were confused by this example (or examples citing this page)

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.ID, "someId")) 
                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

here the lambda is required because the condition is not a provided expected condition but a custom one. it is the "common" `find_element` method. which returns something if found (evaluates to true as far as `wait.until` is concerned) and raises an exception if nothing found (handled by `wait.until`).

you need the lambda because `until` expects a function that accepts a driver as first argument. since the `find_element` is a method of the driver object you need to wrap the lambda around `find_element` so the lambda accepts the driver and calls `find_element` from the driver. any return value or exception is passed up the call chain.

the methods provided in the expected condition module (`from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`) are already returning a closure function (identical to a lambda in this simple case) which accepts a driver and calls the appropriate method from the driver and returning the return value and letting an exception through should one be raised.

if you did this mistake in java your code wouldn't even compile. in python the code compiled and ran because of the "duck typing" philosophy of python. python is very lenient with types and as long as the value is callable in the right context or evaluates to true in a conditional then the value is used and merrily passed allong the call chain.

this philosophy has advantages and disadvantages. you were bitten by the disadvantage. an extraneous lambda. is callable. passed along merrily. no errors but code does not behave as expected. confusion.

ok that might be a bit much deep python fu. you do not need to understand all of that right now but it will help you tremendously programming in python when you learn to understand that stuff.

TL;DR: if using `EC` methods then do not use lambda.

---

even more deep python fu

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#presence_of_element_located

here you see the `EC` methods already returning a closure function (identical to a lambda in this simple case)

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.html#WebDriverWait.until

here you see `wait.until` does not care about the type of the return value. it just tests if it evaluates to true or not. that is why your extraneous lambda is not an error but messes up the logic and semantic of the code.